# How can I switch the js file to call depending on situation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have 3 variables and I want to call different js files which are located in different views.

- if @community => I want to call /views/communities/refresh.js.erb
- if @community_topic => I want to call /views/community_topics/refresh.js.erb
- if @user => I want to call /views/users/refresh.js.erb

How can I code it into this?

```
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to @community, :notice => "comment added!"  }
        format.js { }
    end
```

Comment: why dont you do something like `unless @community.nil? render "communities/refresh.js.erb"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you just want to render the views.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to @community, :notice => "comment added!"  }
  format.js do
    if @community.present?
      render 'communities/refresh' 
    elsif @community_topic.present?
      render 'community_topics/refresh'
    elsif @user.present?
      render 'users/refresh'
    end
  end
end
```

But all in all I think your controller is breaking some basic REST rules, isn't it? Therefore I think you should at first rethink the structure of your controller so that **you have three methods each being responsible for one of those objects** (`@community`, `@community_topic` or `@user`).

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks and I know my way is against REST rule but what if you make the controller called comments_controller.rb, which is used in common and being called from other models to post comments? It's polymorph

Comment: Have a look at [polymorphic associations railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association). It's written for Rails 2.3, but should work fine for Rails 3 as well.